# How voltage is related to frequency in CPU?

Tags: voltage, frequency, cpu

I have a question that what is the relationship between CPU frequency(Clock Speed) and voltage. Does decreasing or increasing the voltage effects the frequency(mean frequency incrases or decreases with voltage). How frequency(Clock Speed) of CPU is inceased or decreased if it is not related to voltage? And what is the relation of V in this equation with frequency(Clock Speed):
*P = CV<sup>2</sup> f*

Comment: The answer to the first three is that they're unrelated; most PC BIOS will let you set them indepentdly.

Comment: 4. V and f are independent variables in *that* equation. Unless there is something not shown which says f is a function of V.

Comment: If OP would say "maximum frequency", the question might make sense. In any case this is a subject of entire optimization of CPU design, and dissertations and thousands engineer-years were devoted to the issue. If this is a classroom assignment, textbooks are written on the basic relationship between dissipated power limit and gate switching frequency for a given voltage supply. I vote to close this as "too broad".

Comment: It's actually a relationship of three variables, voltage clock speed and temperature. Since any particular CPU arrangement can only dump a certain amount of heat through the heat exchanger, you are left messing with the other two to run it at max performance.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, there is none, the frequency is driven by an oscillator, whose frequency may be sometimes changed dynamically.

Consider this :

- Higher voltages makes faster transistors (stronger electric fields for moving electrons).
- More transitions (1->0 or 0->1) and more voltage makes more power dissipation (static power due to leakage and dynamic power due to charge transfers across resistive material).
- There is a limit on the amount of power that may be generated by a chip (there is a maximum working temperature for silicon chips, around 100...150°C)
- With higher temperature, silicon becomes more resistive and leaky, reducing efficiency.

All that stuff combines to the fact than, when properly cooled, with a fan, liquid nitrogen or whatever, a CPU may be able to work reliably at higher frequency than without.

The adjustement of voltage and frequency in relation to the temperature and CPU load is generally part of a regulation system where frequency is lowered when the temperature is too high (to reduce dynamic power dissipation) or when the computer is not used (to save energy). With slower frequency, it may be possible to lower the voltage (to save energy, reduce dissipation) as the transistors don't need to be as fast.

Asynchronous designs, where the working frequency is directly related to the performance of transistors, using the propagation time across gates, delay loops, ... are practically never used : Chips are characterized, with some margins (process variations, aging...) to determine a suitable range of voltages, frequencies and power dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

CPU overclocking generally raises  Vcc in subthreshold logic (Vcc<1V). The goal is ensure the timing margin of the data is maintained by keeping the junction temperature constant with water cooling to limit Tjcn temp to ~70'C max.

RdsOn rises with temp, while RdsOn lowers with rising Vss and which affects rise time and can improve timing margin such that FSB multiplier can be raised slightly.

However this is offset by a slight increase capacitance that increases Cpd with Vss.

Unfortunately Pd increases with the square of Vss and dynamic Pd increases with fclk toggle rate of all bits such that overall timing margins are compromised leading to higher probability of errors.

Thus raising an i8 core from 0.95 to 1.55V reduces rise time by a reduction Rdson which leads to not only an increase dynamic current spikes of about a power exponent of 2.5 (AFAIK) while raising FSB multiplier fCLK might be possible say 3.4GHz to 5.5GHz and thus cooling power demand might rise say from 75W to 350W or much more for all parts related.  ( ballpark) This demands premium watercooling on many parts CPU,RAM,etc, not just a bigger heatsink and lower ESR caps to maintain Vss ripple.